# Why $\langle MSx\;,\;Sx\rangle=\sum_{n>0} \frac1{n^2}\,|x_n|^2\,?$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the operators $M,S$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ given by $Me_n= M(n) e_n$ and $S e_n=\sqrt{S(n)}e_{-n}$ with
$$M(n)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n^2}& n>0,\\
\frac{1}{|n|}& n<0,\\
0&n=0.
\end{cases}
\qquad
S(n)= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n}&n>0,\\
0&\text{else}.
\end{cases},$$
and $e_n$ is the canonical basis of $\ell^2$. Recall that every $x=(x_n)_n\in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ we have
$$x=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} x_ne_n.$$

> For all $x=(x_n)_n\in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, I understand why to prove that
>   $$\langle MSx\;,\;Sx\rangle=\sum_{n>0} \frac1{n^2}\,|x_n|^2\,?$$

Recall that for all $x=(x_n)_n,\; y=(y_n)_n \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ we have
$$\langle x\;,\;y\rangle=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} x_n \overline{y_n}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}x_n e_n \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. Then
$$
 Sx = \sum_{n > 0} n^{-1/2}x_ne_{-n},
$$
and hence
$$
 MSx = \sum_{n > 0} n^{-1/2}x_n\lvert-n\rvert^{-1}e_{-n} = \sum_{n > 0} n^{-3/2}x_ne_{-n},
$$
where $Me_{-n} = \lvert -n \rvert^{-1}e_{-n}$ precisely because $-n < 0$. Now just apply orthonormality of the canonical basis $\{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$.